# Use a custom tensor flow model on Flutter (flutter_tflite 1.0.1)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, tensorflow

I am trying to create an app that can recognize insects from uploaded images, but I am new to all of these things.
To achieve this, I am using this TensorFlow Lite model : https://tfhub.dev/google/lite-model/aiy/vision/classifier/insects_V1/3

But when I'm trying to run my model using the following code :

```
Future imageClassification(File image)
async {
   Uint8List imageBytes = await image.readAsBytes();
   img.Image? imageInput = img.decodeImage(imageBytes);
   img.Image resizedImage = img.copyResize(imageInput!, width: 224, height: 224);
   Uint8List imageInputUint8 = resizedImage.getBytes(format: img.Format.rgb);

   List? recognition = await Tflite.runModelOnBinary(
     binary: imageInputUint8.buffer.asUint8List(),
   );


   setState(() {
     _results = recognition!;
     _image = image;
     imageSelect = true;
   });
 }
```

I get the following error :

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 5943): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.Vector.size()' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime( 5943):    at sq.flutter.flutter_tflite.TflitePlugin.GetTopN(TflitePlugin.java:318)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5943):    at sq.flutter.flutter_tflite.TflitePlugin.access$200(TflitePlugin.java:65)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5943):    at sq.flutter.flutter_tflite.TflitePlugin$RunModelOnBinary.onRunTfliteDone(TflitePlugin.java:570)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5943):    at sq.flutter.flutter_tflite.TflitePlugin$TfliteTask.onPostExecute(TflitePlugin.java:513)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5943):    at sq.flutter.flutter_tflite.TflitePlugin$TfliteTask.onPostExecute(TflitePlugin.java:481)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5943):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:771)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5943):    at android.os.AsyncTask.-$$Nest$mfinish(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5943):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:788)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5943):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5943):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5943):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5943):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5943):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5943):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5943):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
I/Process ( 5943): Sending signal. PID: 5943 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
```

I'm not sure, but it seems to be a problem related to the image format. Maybe I'm not converting it correctly.

Does anyone have an idea where the problem could be? Also, could you please explain why it's not working?